# Linear Boussinesq Equation for groundwater flow in inconfined aquifer?

Tags: models, hydrology, groundwater, water-table

I was reading a [paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2006WR005155/full) (equation 1 in linked paper) where they used 'linearized Boussinesq' equation to model groundwater in unconfined aquifer.  The linearized Boussinesq equation described in the paper was $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = \frac{kh^*}{\phi} \frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x^2}$$ where $k$ is hydraulic conductivity $h^*$ is average height of water table and $\phi$ is specific yield. This equation is very much similar to diffusion equation used normally to model groundwater flow in confined aquifer as defined below.$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = \frac{kd}{S} \frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x^2}$$ where $d$ is thickness and $s$ is storativity of confined aqufier.  When I googled about Boussinest equation, it is noway similar to what I have presented above. My question is is 'linearized form of Boussinesq equation similar to diffusion equation in this case? If yes then how?

Comment: can you edit your question to show the reference of the paper you are reading ?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BoussinesqEquation.html the linear boussinesq equation as presented here is similar to what you have in the paper. You take the total material derivative. Set the advective non linear terms to be zero and then you have that equal to the RHS

Comment: @gansub how? The partial derivative w.r.t time is second derivative in the given link? Also the term on right hand side of equation 1 in link as no corresponding term in the equation that I have given here.

Comment: you write out the total material derivative - you have two terms - one the partial deriviative of h with respect to t and the advection term. The advection term is nonlinear and you set it to zero. Then you have a linear form of the material derivative. Regarding the right hand side you will have to explain from hydrology  what that is.